# change the position of boxes in boxplot in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following code from two different `*.m` file and I need to plot in such a way that position one should be filled by the box of `l` and second position should be filled by the box from `b` and similarly for third and fourth box.

```
k=[2.3844 379.8351 990.1233; .1889 9.3867 54.350] ;
l=k';
boxplot(l)

%% second code 

a=[0.1890, 9.3867,54.3505;1.8792,27.5678,86.1677];
b=a';
boxplot(b)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: after running the above two different code in two different editor in mat lab we will get two separate fig. My first question how to plot these two separate fig. together in such a way that  position one of single graph(together) should be filled by the box of first fig  and second position should be filled by the box from second fig and similarly for third and fourth box

Comment: Is [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/22-how-do-i-display-different-boxplot-groups-on-the-same-figure-in-matlab) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708175/hierarchically-grouped-boxplot) an answer to your question?

Comment: m7913d i am not getting what u want to say

Comment: here position is w.r.t x-axis