# Have multiple box plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, boxplot

I have two boxplot diagrams in matlab which are the following one:

```
boxplot(input1(:,2), input1(:,1)) % time accompilishing a task among genders (male/female)
boxplot(input2(:,2), input2(:,1)) % time accompilishing a task among degree (bachelor/master)
```

What I want is to compine both diagrams in the same plot. So for the four cases in x-axis to have the time in y-axis. How can I do so?

Comment: For more advanced options you might want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708175/hierarchically-grouped-boxplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by simply concatenating the tables vertically:

```
input = [input1;input2];
boxplot(input(:,2), input(:,1))
```

This is assuming that the groups in `input1` have different keys than the ones in `input2`. E.g. If `male = 1`, `female = 2` and `bachelor = 1`, `master = 2` it will "mix" the classes without throwing an error. In that case you would have to assign unique keys beforehand.